# Where are folders created by "sudo mkdir" stored?

Tags: terminal, sudo

I am new to mac terminal and I have made some folder using command "sudo mkdir". Some of this folders are hidden :/, in other words I have put a period before their names when using command mkdir. Now, I want to delete those folders. How can I find those folders?

Comment: Does `ls -al $HOME` reveal these directories?

Comment: Which directory were you in when you ran the command.

Comment: @Mark I was in the home directory, the one dedicated to current user

Comment: @fd0 I tried different options like u what u say, but I did not found the folder I had made. Actually I do not know where those folders are made, otherwise I would use 'ls -a'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mkdir`, in the form of `mkdir directory_name` without a pathname, creates a directory in the current working directory, which is by default your home directory (often represented as `~`). You can check you current working directory by running `pwd`.

If you were not in your home directory (either by having `cd`-ed to a different directory or having used the `New Terminal at Folder` Service) you will have to navigate to the directory you were in first.

You can show all files (including hidden ones) in a directory by running `ls -a` in it. Once you have found the directories you want to delete, you can permanently (!) remove them using `rm -R directoryNameHere` (including the `.` in the name) from their parent directory.

If you don't feel confident deleting files in the Terminal, you can simply show hidden file in Finder, in macOS Sierra and later, by using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> and then deleting them like you would any other directory.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is it possible that a command fails without any message in terminal? I searched for the folders in the directory I was was working, but I did not find them. I guess  that commands simply did not run.

Comment: There is still sth I do not get. I have added 'sudo' at the beginning of the code. Does that mean folders are created in the main root directory?

Comment: @Arman, If you preface the `mkdir` command with `sudo` it doesn't change where the directory is created, only its ownership. In other words, using e.g.  `sudo mkdir directory_name` causes `directory_name` to be owned by `root`, but is still created in the present working directory (`pwd`) assuming an explicit `pathname` what not a part of `directory_name`.